# Calculating the date weeks using the date() function

Tags: php, date

I have a website which saves images into a database. I have successfully made a function that calculates the date that an image is added and this value is also saved into the database. I now want to calculate the date two weeks ahead from the addition date. This will show the date that the image file will cease to exist in the database.
I used the function:

```
$dateofaddedimage= date("d/m/Y");
```

This calculate thee current date of the addition of the image.

I am aware that there is the strtodate() function, but i don't think it will help.

Does anyone know how to add two weeks onto this function?
Thanks!

Comment: while inserting `DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 2 WEEK)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a number to `time()`, which is the current time stamp as seconds from the Unix Epoch.

```
$twoweeks = time() + (2*7*24*60*60);
$thatasdate = date("d/m/Y", $twoweeks) ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out [date_add](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date-add.php) and the PHP DateTime model.
From the php manual page comes this fine example:

```
<?php
$date = new DateTime('2000-01-01');
$date->add(new DateInterval('P10D'));
echo $date->format('Y-m-d') . "\n";
```

If you use this on your problem, you'd have

```
<?php
$dateofaddedimage   = new DateTime('now'); //creates DateTime Model of today (and now)
$dateofimagedestroy = new DateTime('now'); //creates DateTime Model of today as well
$dateofimagedestroy->add(new DateInterval('P14D')); // adds 14 Days to the second date
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with what you are doing is that `date()` returns a string formatted to the date - not a proper date.

I would suggest either inserting a datetime into the database such as:

```
insert into yourTable (timeColumn) values (now());
```

This will insert the actual date. From there you can use mysql functions to add and subtract from this date.

Or using a timestamp in your code such as:

```
$uploadedTime=time();
```

From there you can either use PHP functions to add or subtract dates, or (as it is a timestamp) you can also use mysql functions to calculate what you need inside queries themselves.